# WHERE a OR b IN (x) does not match, but returns rows

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, where-in

My table looks like this:

```
| a  | ts_9 | ts_11 |
|----|------|-------|
| yx | 0    |       |
| xy | 0    |       |
```

And for some reason the rows get returned when I call:

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE ts_9 IN ("asdewdwedewd") OR ts_11 IN ("asdewdwedewd")
```

Why does that happen?

Feel free to recreate it in your db with copy paste:

```
CREATE TABLE `things` (
  `a` char(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ts_9` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
  `ts_11` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a` (`a`) );

INSERT INTO `things` (`a`, `ts_9`, `ts_11`) VALUES ('yx', '0', ''), ('xy', '0', '');
```

Comment: My guess is that string is being cast into an integer.

Comment: @Uueerdo great guess, thanks! is there any generic prevention to avoid this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of offhand is don't mix numeric and string types in expressions involving equality unless you can guarantee the strings parse correctly.

Comment: Note that `x IN (single-item)` is essentially the same as `x = single-item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ts_9 IN ("asdewdwedewd")` evaluated to true. More specifically, `ts_9` has value of integer `0`. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type
>   of expr

In other words, `"asdewdwedewd"` will be treated as an int. When mysql convert it to an int `cast("asdewdwedewd" as signed integer)`, we get `0`. Hence `0 in (0)` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer brings the data to the same type.
When translating a string to decimal, we get zero.
It is necessary to predefine or convert data types.

Comment: String to decimal does not always yield 0; for example, casting "1.5676asdafnenawuiawuin" and "1asdkjaklfkl" to DECIMAL(5,2) results in 1.57 and 1.00 respectively.